# I am try to get object of the logged in user in django? This list that is been created while form.save of the user that is logged in

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hello as I posted here before I new to django python need some help on how to get objects of a user that is currently logged in. I have an app named stores which contains a models named Store. I just want to gather the list of stores a user created. Do I have to add anything in setting.py ?

I am really confused about it I also tried request.user and tried to filter the object but I wasn't able to do it. I am posting my code over here kindly look into it and do let me know.

Do let me know if you need anything else to understand.

views.py of stores app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import NewStore
from .models import Store


def store(request):
    form = NewStore()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStore(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save()

            return redirect('stores_list')

        else:
            form = NewStore()
    return render(request, "default/store.html", {'form': form})


@login_required()
def stores_list(request):
    my_stores = Store.objects.all()
    print(my_stores)
    return render(request, "default/stores_list.html", {'my_list': my_stores})
```

models.py of stores app

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Store(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

stores_list.html

```
{% extends 'default/base.html' %}
<html>
<head><title>E-Commerce App</title></head>
{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome to your profile</h1>
    <h2>Stores List</h2>
    <p>This is your store list</p>

    <ul>
        {% for s in my_list %}
        <li> Store {{ s.id }}: {{ s.name }}  </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
 {% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: form.save() instead form = form.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStore(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save()
            return redirect('stores_list')
```

to

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStore(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entry = form.save(commit=False)
            # Attach logged-in user details with the 'store' entry
            entry.user = request.user
            entry.save()
            return redirect('stores_list')
```

To **get the store list**, created under the logged in user, use

```
logged_in_user = request.user
store_list = Store.objects.filter(user=logged_in_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter all stores for those belonging to the current user:

```
@login_required()
def stores_list(request):
    my_stores = Store.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    print(my_stores)
    return render(request, "default/stores_list.html", {'my_list': my_stores})
```

Comment: I'd be very thankful to you if you solved this or guided me on this thank you !

Comment: do you get any errors or just not the output you expect?

Comment: and you are sure that you have store objects saved in the database?
the list will be empty if there are no stores created yet. (your form evaluating has a mistake 
form = form.save() 
should be
form.save()

Comment: Yes it does, when I use Store.objects.all() it shows me the whole list of the stores that are being created.

Comment: well then the currently logged in user hasnt created any of the stores. hence you cannot see any after the filter gets applied

Comment: Change 

    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save()
with

    if form.is_valid():
        entry = form.save(commit=False)
        entry.user = request.user
        entry.save()

Comment: Well I did created it on all of the users I created.

Comment: No let again I did the same as you said

Comment: Yeah it worked as i created new store  thank you very much it took quite alot of my time I could say 6 to 7 hours I tried everything changed the whole stores_list. Thank you again!